# how to connect to db2 unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

First go to `/dvdev/dv/bin`
Type:

```
./dvdev/dv/.dvprofile
export PATH  
$DBPRFPATH  
$DBCNTCMD  
db2
```

Please let me know how to perform simple connection steps in Unix shell script

Answer (score 0):

The script is simple, calling it not so simple

```
$ cat simple.sh
cd /dvdev/dv/bin
. /dvdev/dv/.dvprofile
export PATH
$DBPRFPATH
$DBCNTCMD
db2
```

When the script is finished everything that the script has set in the environment
is forgotten: the subshell is finished. The script calls db2, so db2 works ok.
When you want the settings valid after finishing the script, you should "source"the file (calling with a dot):

```
$ . simple.sh
```

When you like to have these settings all the times, you might want to append them to your .profile or .bashrc.